# Underscore: Find the most frequently occurring object in an array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have here an array of object.

```
var list = [
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 100, "name": "Kevin"},
    {"id": 120, "name": "Max"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"}
];
```

I need to extract from this array, the most frequent occurring object and build a new array of it ordered by the most popular name.

So far, I have tried to follow the way it was done from this topic : [Underscore.js: Find the most frequently occurring value in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878571/underscore-js-find-the-most-frequently-occurring-value-in-an-array)

```
// Build temp list
temp_list = _(
    _.chain(
        _(list).pluck('id')
    )
    .countBy()
    .pairs()
    .value()
)
.sortBy(1)
.reverse();

// Build final list with most frequently occurring first
_.map(temp_list, function(current) {
    return _.findWhere(list, {
        'id': parseInt(current[0])
    });
});
```

Could exists a way to improve this code by sorting directly initial list without the need to create a temp list ?

Comment: All objects in your array are different. Do you want to consider two objects to be equal if their `id` and `name` properties coincide? Only `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just about got it: you could call map right off the `reverse` call. Here's how I did it:

```
var newlist = _.chain(list)
    .countBy(function (item) { return item.id; })
    .pairs()
    .sortBy(function (item) { return item[1]; })
    .reverse()
    .map(function (item) { return _.findWhere(list, { id: parseInt(item[0]) }); })
    .value();
```

The breakdown:

> **chain**: returns a wrapped version of the array, that let's you chain underscore functions.
>
> **countBy**: returns an object where the keys are whatever value is returned from the callback, and the values are the number of times those keys occured.
>
> **pairs**: converts `{ key: 'value' }` to `['key', 'value']`
>
> **sortBy**: returns an array sorted by the value returned from the callback
>
> **reverse**: reverses the array
>
> **map**: returns a new array where each item is based on the item in the original array at that index and whatever is done to that value in the callback. In this case, we're using the `id` (`item[0]`) to get the object from the original list.
>
> **value**: unwraps the chain-able object and returns the "raw" value.

Answer (score 2):

```
_.chain(list)
    .countBy("id").pairs().sortBy()
    .reverse().map(function (element) {return _.findWhere(list, { id: parseInt(element[0]) }); }).value()
```

```js
var list = [
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 100, "name": "Kevin"},
    {"id": 120, "name": "Max"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"}
];
var result = _.chain(list)
    .countBy("id").pairs().sortBy()
    .reverse().map(function (element) {return _.findWhere(list, { id: parseInt(element[0]) }); }).value();
console.log(result);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), to get a count of items, after that a [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

Something like this

```js
var list = [
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"},
    {"id": 100, "name": "Kevin"},
    {"id": 120, "name": "Max"},
    {"id": 439, "name": "John"}
];

var finalList = _.chain(list)
 .reduce(function(memo, item){
 var previous = _.findWhere(memo,{id:item.id});
  if(previous){
   previous.count++;
  }else{
   item.count=1;
   memo.push(item);
  }
  return memo;
},[])
 .sortBy('count')
  .reverse()
  .value();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```